# C++ folder opening and file counting

Tags: c++, file, count, directory

So this is my code but I cant prevent it from printing out: . .. and it counts them as a file. I couldnt understand why.
The output is:

```
.
1files.
..
2files.
course3.txt
3files.
course2.txt
4files.
course1.txt
5files.
```

But there are only 3 files... It should say 3 files instead it counts that . .. and i dont know its meaning.

```
int folderO(){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    int nFiles=0;
    if ((dir = opendir ("sampleFolder")) != NULL) {
      /* print all the files and directories within directory */
      while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
        std::cout << ent->d_name << std::endl;
        nFiles++;
        std::cout << nFiles << "files." << std::endl;
      }
      closedir (dir);
    } 
    else {
      /* could not open directory */
      perror ("");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I implemented  the way i wanted though?

Comment: I don't see any code here to filter out `.` and `..`, so I don't understand your surprise that they appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. and .. are meta directories, current directory and parent directory respectively.

What you have found is that subdirectories are being printed along with files. And so are symlinks and other "weird" Unix-y stuff. Couple ways to filter those out if you don't want them printed:

If your system supports `d_type` in the `dirent` structure, check that `d_type == DT_FILE` before printing. ([GNU page on `dirent` listing possible d_types](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html))

```
if (ent->d_type == DT_FILE)
{
    std::cout << ent->d_name << std::endl;
    nFiles++;
    std::cout << nFiles << "files." << std::endl;
}
```

if `d_type` is not supported, [`stat` the file name and check that it is a file `st_mode == S_ISREG`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

```
struct stat statresult;
if (stat(ent->d_name, &statresult) == 0)
{
    if (statresult.st_mode == S_ISREG)
    {
        std::cout << ent->d_name << std::endl;
        nFiles++;
        std::cout << nFiles << "files." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And of course there is the dumb-simple `strcmp`-based if statement, but this will list all other subdirectories.

Crap. Sorry. C++. that last line should be "And of course there is the dumb-simple `std::string` `operator==`-based if statement, but this will list all other subdirectories."

Answer (score 0):

`.` is current directory inode (technically, a hardlink), `..` is parent directory.

These are there for navigation. They're directories, perhaps you can ignore them if they are directories?

Comment: Can I implemented the way i wanted though? I have got to get rid of those or i need to find only .txt files. How would that be possible?

Comment: @hfakar You can `strcmp(ent->d_name, ".")` and skip it.

Comment: @hfakar: An `if` statement, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

A Google search would have revealed that these are special folder names with these meanings:

- `.` the current directory
- `..` the parent directory

Any tutorial on iterating a directory shows you how to filter these out with a simple "if" statement.